# Big Query Error: No matching signature for operator = for argument types: BOOL, INT64

Tags: google-bigquery

I connected dataset in Big Query to Tableau and running the below code. Which should return trucks that have been stationary.

```
SELECT 
    b1.city , 
    b1.state ,
    COUNT(DISTINCT b1.truck) AS Count
FROM `iot`.`test_data` AS b1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
            DISTINCT assetPrefixNumber
    FROM `iot`.`test_data`
    WHERE assetMoving = 1
) AS b2 
ON b1.truck = b2.truck
WHERE 
    b2.truck IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    b1.city ,
    b1.state
```

I am getting this error:
An error occurred while communicating with the data source

Error Code: 015CFBE6
The Google BigQuery service was unable to compile the query.
No matching signature for operator = for argument types: BOOL, INT64. Supported signature: ANY = ANY at [12:15]

From my understanding, seems the problem is at ON statement where data types are not matching. Unfortunately, I dont have access to data in bigquery to look into it. From similar datasets in other databases
Truck, City, State - VARCHAR(50)
assetMoving - Boolean

Please give me some clue on how to resolve this error.

Thanks in advance

I tried using CAST to INT64 at ON statement, but that didn't work. This is my first time working with Bigquery, not sure what else I can try

Comment: in the select statement of `b2`, the column `truck` is missing.